# What does: "$("#somediv").css('top', pos > 0 ? pos : 0);" mean

Tags: jquery, css

I have the jquery expression `toolbar.css('top', pos > 0 ? pos : 0);` ... `pos` is a numeric variable that is calculated above (but not shown here, as it's not relevant).

I am trying to work out what `pos > 0 ? pos : 0` means?

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if pos is greater than 0, return pos, otherwise return 0

Its called a Ternary Operation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 2):

General syntax for ? : syntax

```
(if true) ? (then) : (else)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the css position property of the toolbar element is greater than 0, it will set it to the value of the pos variable, else it will set it to 0.

it uses the [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator

Answer (score 0):

It's called ternary operation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 0):

pos > 0 ? pos : 0 is a ternary operation. A more verbose way of putting it would be:

```
if(pos > 0) {
   return pos;
}
else {
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may well write the same as

```
toolbar.css('top', pos);
```

if `pos` wont ever be less than zero

Comment: No, not really: for `pos` < 0 this is incorrect (as the OP does not say that `pos` is always zero or greater)